# handling intents using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, xml

Please how can i use a button in an intro activity that when pressed will take me to the main activity. The intro page is meant to show on the first use of the app.

here is my IntroActivity.java onCreate method

```
Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {

                Intent switchSwag = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(switchSwag);
                finish();
            } else {
                Editor ed = pref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
                ed.commit();
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to show the intro activity only during the first time the app is started. Add the following code inside onCreate and NOT in on button click.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)) {

            Intent switchSwag = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(switchSwag);
            finish();
        } else {
            Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.commit();
        }
```

Then managing button click:

```
Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchButton);
switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent switchSwag = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(switchSwag);
            finish();
    }

});
```